# Arithmetic Progression with a Modular Series

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the arithmetic progression $0, b, 2b, 3b, ...$. Suppose $(d,b)=1$, meaning they are relatively prime. Prove that the series $\{kb (\text{mod}\,d)\}, k=1, 2, ...$ contains $d$ different residues.

I am assuming that $k$ is supposed to go from $1$ to $d$ and not on forever as was given to me. However, it has been a very long time since I have dealt with modular arithmetic, let alone with series involving modular arithmetic and I am struggling with finding a good starting point for the proof.

It seems obvious to me that when working with $\text{mod}\,d$ that there would be $d$ different residues, from $0$ to $d-1$ because after that the numbers would cycle through again.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $ka\equiv kb \pmod{d}$.  Then $k(a-b)\equiv 0 \pmod{d}\Rightarrow d|k(a-b)$

As $(d,b)=1$, $d|(a-b)\Rightarrow a\equiv b\pmod{d}.$  Thus $a\not\equiv b\pmod{d}\Rightarrow ka\not\equiv kb\pmod{d}$  and therefore multiplication by $k$ is an injective map (which, in finite groups of the same size, also implies surjectivity).  Therefore $k\cdot \mathbb{Z}_d\simeq \mathbb{Z}_d$ (note: I only proved bijection, and didn't actually prove isomorphism, but you can do that if you want)

Comment: Do you mean multiplying by $k$ instead of by $d$?